# iOS tagging like button that can move down if not enough space

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please take a look at the attached image
[image: keyword]

I can make one button like in the picture, but I don't know how to keep adding buttons to the view, and if there's not enough space, the new button will go to the next line. Also the view for Music should move down accordingly.

I'm not sure if I have to make a custom view for the whole Movies thing, or just calculate the button size and add it to the view.

Please help me with an approach for doing this.

Comment: I'm trying to add button to the view and calculate button size ... but that takes too much works, and I'm trying to figure out the better way to do this

Comment: `UICollectionView` will be abetter choice for you

Comment: But how to apply UICollectionView for this case exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a `UICollectionView`. This is exactly what it has been built for.

You can have the buttons adjust their size automatically based on the title string and the collection view (more specifically, the flow layout) will do all the wrapping and displaying for you.

Explaining in detail how exactly a collection view works would be beyond the scope of this question, see the [UICollectionView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, btw, how to handle moving the Music section down? Do u suggest the Music to be another collectionView and move it down according to the height of Movies collection view?

Comment: No, collection views have sections and items. So you can maintain several sections in one collection view.

Comment: But how to apply UICollectionView for this case exactly?

Comment: As stated in the answer, I this is beyond the scope of the question. You should refer to the above mentioned documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To do it manually....

Create separate UIView containers for movies and Music (then it will be easier to move down music), but Yes - simply add necessary buttons to the view and calculate button size and reposition them accordingly.

For example:

```
NSArray *names = @[@"Lion King", @"Marley and me", @"Super duper"];

        for(UIView *view in [_moviewView subviews]) //we hide all buttons, in case this time there are some buttons which will not be used
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                [view setHidden:YES];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < [names count]; i++)
        {
            UIButton *button = [_moviesView viewWithTag:i+100]; //To make sure we actually touch buttons instead of other subviews, if we presume, that _moviesView will have up tofew other subviews which will have no tags.

            if(!button)
            {
                button = [UIButton new];

                [button setTag:i+100];

                [_moviesView addSubview:button];
            }

            [button setTitle:names[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [button setHidden:NO];   //unhide - we will use this button as we have a name for it.

            //more button adjustments
        }

        int currentX = 0;

        int currentY = 0;

        for(UIButton *button in [_moviesView subviews])
        {
            if(button.tag >= 100)
            {
                CGSize *buttonSize = ...//Calculate button width based on title?

                if(buttonSize.width + currentX >= _moviesView.frame.size.width) //in case this button will go outside boundaries - position it on next line.
                {
                    currentY += 30 + 5; //constant button height? + 5 space

                    currentX = 0; // reset x.
                }

                [button setFrame:CGRectMake(currentX, currentY, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height)];

                currentX += buttonSize.width + 5; //5 - space between buttons

            }
        }

        //And now - based on our currentY (+30 button height)  we can resize moviesView and then reposition musicView, for which we would do the same..
```

I hope You get the Idea.. Good luck!